# Django User Class Inheritance

Tags: django

Apologies for this question but I wasn't sure how to get assistance.  I'm slowly learning Django (around 2 months in) and trying to work out how to enable user authentication into my website.  I've been reading about 3 different ways to do this; OneToOne link to the User class, Subclass the User class or changing the AUTH_USER_MODEL (although not following that one at the momement).

I'm getting myself confused which way to go and would like advice.  I'm looking at either OneToOne or creating my own based on the User class.  Are there any advantages to one way or the other before I decide which way to go ?

Thanks in advance, there is no where else I can turn.

Regards

Wayne

Comment: The second and third options are the same. If you subclass, you need to change AUTH_USER_MODEL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, as it often is with vague questions, it completely depends.

Out of the box, you can use the built in auth models to allow users basic access to your sites... that's kind of the whole point of the auth package. If that's all you're looking to do just leverage Auth.User

The question really becomes, what do you need that the built in auth model is not providing you? When you can answer that question, you'll have a better idea of whether you need to override with a custom auth class, simply extend a user profile, or foreign key into other custom data models.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @daniel-petrikin.  All i need is to allow authentication with some addition fields that are not availabe in the built in auth model.  I think I'll just go with extending a user profile by referencing the user class with a OneToOne mapping to save messing with AUTH_USER_MODEL.  Dont quite get that currently so will wait until I've grasped more of the basics first.  Thanks. Wayne

Comment: That's what a user profile is for. Overriding the auth model usually implies some custom authentication or other advanced usage. Additional tracking of basic fields definitely should just be a user profile

Comment: Thanks for helping, this is the only place I can find as a sounding board for newbies to ask question while learning.  Sorry if these questions seem basic.  Thanks again.